# One state updates faster than another creating double calculation

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component looking something like:

```
const MyComponent  = () => {
    const data = dataSetter((state) => state.data);
    const type = typeSetter((state) => state.type);

    if (!Array.isArray(data) || !data.length) {
        return <p>No data loaded yet</p>;
    }

    const colNames = Object.keys(data);

    const dataArrays = {};
    colNames.forEach((key) => {
        dataArrays[key] = data.map((object) => object[key]);
    });

    const chosenOption = "col1"


    const vals1 = dataArrays[type];
    const vals2 = dataArrays[chosenOption].map((v, i) => v - vals1[i]);
```

`data` is a fetch, `type` is just a tab, where I can change the value. It then create two arrays in the end based of the data from `dataArrays`, where `vals2` is dependent on `vals1`, i.e. the arrays are subtracted.

My problem is that when I click my tab to change `type` that's pretty much instant. However, this change also triggers a new fetch/refetch that updates the `data`. But this fetch is a tiny bit slower than just setting the `type`. This means that `vals2` is first updated/recalculated with the old `dataArrays` data but the new `type` (which updates instantly), and then once again when `dataArrays` is updated.

So on my screen I can see the values from `vals2` change two times, instead of just changing when both ´dataArrays`and`type` is updated.

I've tried to introduce some useState hooks for `vals2`, but I seem to keep running into errors such as: "Error fetching data: Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

So is there an easy way to fix this, or do I need to rethink how I do it?

EDIT (more code):

This is the fetch method, which is triggered upon loading the main component, and then every time `type` is changed:

```
const fetchMyData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${fetchUrl}/data`, {
                type: type,
            });

            if (res.data) {
                setData({
                    df: res.data,
                });
                return res.data;
            } else {
                console.error("No data received from server");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        }
    };

    useQuery({
        queryKey: ["data", type],
        queryFn: fetchMyData,
        retry: false,
    });
```

My Zustand store for this data is:

```
import { create } from "zustand";

type State = {
    data: any;
    setData: (data: any) => void;
};

const returnObjects = {
    data: [],
};

const myData = create<State>((set) => ({
    data: returnObjects,
    setData: (data) => set({ data }),
}));

export default myData;
```

For the `type` the store looks like:

```
type State = {
    type: string;
    setType: (type: string) => void;
    types: string[];
};

const types = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];

const typeSetter = create<State>((set) => ({
    type: "col1",
    setType: (type) => set({ type }),
    types: types,
}));

export default typeSetter;
```

Comment: Clear the `data` when the tab is changed

Comment: Can you show the async fetch code and how it is bound to your component. I.e where the fetch is actually triggered. Are you using redux or something, or is this just plain state? It'd be much easier to answer if we could see the store you are using and how this is configured. Also state what your preferred display is when its in this "interim" state. Do you want it show the old values until both are ready then patch them in? Or nothing until both are ready?

Comment: @adsy I have now added additional code.